# OpenGL: Divide by w of zero

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, lwjgl

I'm currently trying to implement a Camera class, complete with frustum, that I can use for culling objects from the scene.  To find the bounds of the frustum, I'm transforming the system coordinate space (cube with sides ranging [-1..1] each) by the *inverse* of the PVM matrix.  This seems to be working flawlessly, except...

When transforming the origin (0, 0, 0, 1) by the inverse PVM matrix for testing purposes, I get (0, 0, 0, *0*).  I know exactly why it's happening given the particular values of the PVM matrix whilst debugging, but I'm wondering if I'm logically doing something wrong, since as far as I know, the Euclidian point should be (0, 0, 0), not a bunch of NaNs resulting from a w of 0.  What am I forgetting here?  Am I not supposed to divide by w?  Are my matrices are wrong?  Blargh...

### More details:

Projection matrix is defined by the following method (using LWJGL in Java):

```
/** fieldOfView is in radians, aspectRatio is simply width / height. */
public static Matrix4f makeProjectionMatrix(Matrix4f dest, float fieldOfView, float aspectRatio, float nearPlane, float farPlane)
{
    float y_scale = GLUtils.cotan(fieldOfView * .5f);
    float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;
    float frustumLength = farPlane - nearPlane;

    dest.setIdentity();
    dest.m00 = x_scale;
    dest.m11 = y_scale;
    dest.m22 = -(farPlane + nearPlane) / frustumLength;
    dest.m23 = -1f;
    dest.m32 = -2f * nearPlane * farPlane / frustumLength;
    dest.m33 = 0f;

    return dest;
}
```

*Based on http://unspecified.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/calculating-the-gluperspective-matrix-and-other-opengl-matrix-maths/

Notice that m33 is always 0, which happens to be true for my inverse as well (and I believe to be true of all inverses given the above formula).

Since the Model and View are both the identity matrix, and the Projection is unmodified from the above, a coordinate (0, 0, 0, x) transformed by the *inverse* PVM matrix would always yield w of 0... right?

Example matrices causing the dilemma:

Original Projection:

```
1.732 0     0  0
0     1.732 0  0
0     0     0 -2
0     0    -1  0
```

Inverted Projection:

```
.577 0    0   0
0    .577 0   0
0    0    0  -1
0    0   -.5  0
```

I'd be happy to post additional code if a miscalculation is evident.

Comment: m33 being zero is immaterial.  z should end up as -.5 or -1 (depending on row major or column major).  The problem therefore lies in your matrix vector multiplication code. Basically your input z is 0 so your w ends up as 0.  This is normal.  You shouldn't have your input z as 0 ...

Comment: Oops, you're right-- still doesn't change w being 0, though.  I'll fix the post.  So, you're saying my w should be 0?  And why shouldn't my input z be 0?

Comment: Er, I mean is there some reason besides z of 0 producing w of 0 that I shouldn't use z of 0?  Is it totally arbitrary, or is there some reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to the comments:

Well a z of 0 produces a w of 0 because thats what your projection matrix says to do ;)  That said in projection space a z of 0 is right at the origin of the projection.  it needs to be in front of the projection to be visible. Otherwise both the center of projection AND the vertex position occupy the exact same location.  This is why we have near planes to prevent any geometry with a w of 0 (or close to) getting drawn.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense, thanks for explanation.  That does raise another question, though-- does that imply a negative near plane is invalid?  Blegh, there's probably some reading somewhere I need to do...

Comment: @Philip: Re: the negative plane ... that depends on your projection matrix really.  But you are forced to either use a positive or negative near plane.  Its kind of like the way you can only see things in front of you and not behind you.